# Make an html5 audio playlist that automatically plays one song after the next

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I would like to setup an HTML5 audio playlist that automatically plays one song after the next. Here is my start point:

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="example.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="example.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="example.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="example.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="example.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

What is the basic way to make this happen using JavaScript?

Comment: Probably noone will write the whole thing for you. You should do some research (you can start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)), try it yourself, and ask specific questions if you stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do. But, you should look into this jQuery plugin.. They have very good tutorials on their home page.

http://mediaelementjs.com/

If you would like more player.

http://www.narga.net/awesome-jquery-audio-video-player-plugins/

or google : jQuery audio players